# How to save autogenerated UUID to a table in Springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, eclipselink, mssql-jdbc

I am new to springboot and would really appreciate some help. My task is as follows:

1. Insert & store Json data into Input Table (using eclipselink)
   One of the datain this table is an UUID which is randomly generated in Service Implementation.

2.The UUID generated by the ServiceImplementation.class is then stored in a Trigger Table.

I need help with storing the UUID into the Trigger Table as I can't find a suitable method online.

Note: I have a repository class for both Entities.

If you need me to add any other additional code snippets please do let me know. Thanks in advance!

Controller.java

```
package de.cibplus.cibplusngvdpGKZ.Controller;


import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import de.cibplus.cibplusngvdpGKZ.Model.GKZ;
import de.cibplus.cibplusngvdpGKZ.Model.GKZtrigger;
import de.cibplus.cibplusngvdpGKZ.Service.GKZService;



@RestController //@Controller + @ResponseBody
public class GKZController {
    
    @Autowired
    private GKZService gService;
    
    
    
    //Save Input data
        @PostMapping("/gkz")
        public  ResponseEntity<GKZ> saveGKZ(@RequestBody GKZ GKZ) {
        GKZ gkz = gService.saveGKZ(GKZ);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(gkz) ;
            
        }
    
    
    }
    

}
```

Input.class

```
package de.cibplus.cibplusngvdpGKZ.Model;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.time.LocalDate;
//import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.UuidGenerator;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
@Entity

@Table(name= "T_CIB_CIBp_GKZ_I")
public class GKZ {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        
        @Column(name="ID")
        private Integer ID;
        
        @Column(name="stichtag")
        private LocalDate stichtag;
        
        @Column(name="refstreet")
        private String refstreet;
        
        @Column(name="hnr")
        private String hnr;
        
        @Column(name="street")
        private String street;
        
        @Column(name="city")
        private String city;
        
        @Column(name="zipcode")
        private String zipcode;
    
        @Column(name="objecttype_id")
        private Integer objecttypeId;
        
        @Column(name="client_id")
        private String client_id;
        
        @Column(name="valuation_id")
        private BigInteger valuation_id;
        

        
        
        @Column(name="uid")
        private UUID uid;
        
        public LocalDate getstichtag() {
             return stichtag;
         }
        

        public void setstichtag(LocalDate stichtag) {
              this.stichtag = stichtag;
           }

         
         public String getrefstreet() {
             return refstreet;
         }
         
         public void setrefstreet(String refstreet) {
              this.refstreet = refstreet;
           }
         
         public String gethnr() {
             return hnr;
         }
         
         public void sethnr(String hnr) {
              this.hnr = hnr;
           }
         
         public String getstreet() {
             return street;
         }
         
         public void setstreet(String street) {
              this.street = street;
           }
         
         public String getcity() {
             return city;
         }
         
         public void setcity(String city) {
              this.city = city;
           }
         
         public String getzipcode() {
             return zipcode;
         }
         
         public void setzipcode(String zipcode) {
              this.zipcode = zipcode;
           }
         
         public Integer getobjecttypeId() {
             return objecttypeId;
         }
         
         public void setobjecttype_id(Integer objecttypeId) {
              this.objecttypeId = objecttypeId;
           }
         
         public String getclient_id() {
             return client_id;
         }
         
         public void setclient_id(String client_id) {
              this.client_id = client_id;
           }
         
         public BigInteger getvaluation_id() {
             return valuation_id;
         }
         
         public void setvaluation_id(BigInteger valuation_id) {
              this.valuation_id = valuation_id;
           }
         
         public UUID getuid() {
             return uid;
         }
         
         public void setuid(UUID uid) {
              this.uid = uid;
           }
         
         public Integer getID() {
             return ID;
         }
         
         public void setID(Integer ID) {
              this.ID = ID;
           }
        
        
            
            
        }
```

Trigger.class

```
package de.cibplus.cibplusngvdpGKZ.Model;

import java.util.UUID;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;


@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name= "T_CIB_CIBp_uid")
public class GKZtrigger {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Integer ID;
 
    
    @Column(name="uid")
    private UUID uid;
    
    public UUID getuid() {
         return uid;
     }
     
     public void setuid(UUID uid) {
          this.uid = uid;
       }

    public Integer getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(Integer iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }

}
```

Service.class

```
package de.cibplus.cibplusngvdpGKZ.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import de.cibplus.cibplusngvdpGKZ.Model.GKZ;
import de.cibplus.cibplusngvdpGKZ.Model.GKZtrigger;



public interface GKZService {
    
    

    GKZ saveGKZ(GKZ GKZ);
    
    
}
```

ServiceImplementation.class

```
package de.cibplus.cibplusngvdpGKZ.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


import de.cibplus.cibplusngvdpGKZ.Model.GKZ;
import de.cibplus.cibplusngvdpGKZ.Model.GKZtrigger;

import de.cibplus.cibplusngvdpGKZ.Repository.GKZInputRepository;
import de.cibplus.cibplusngvdpGKZ.Repository.GKZTriggerRepository;

import de.cibplus.cibplusngvdpGKZ.Service.*;


@Service
public class GKZServiceImpl implements GKZService {
    
    
    @Autowired
    private GKZInputRepository gRepository;
    
    
    
    @Override
    public GKZ saveGKZ(GKZ GKZ) {

        //Generate random UUID
        UUID uuid=UUID.randomUUID();  
        GKZ.setuid(uuid);
        
        gRepository.save(GKZ);
        
        return GKZ;
        
    }
    
    
    }
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Apart from the in-CAPS-written-variables, everything looks fine to me on a first glance. Can you further elaborate?

Comment: @Z-100  I have no method to store the generated UUID into the trigger table. I have only completed the part to store the UUID into the input table.  I need help with storing the UUID generated also into the trigger table.

Comment: That should be done automatically by JPA. Is there any error stating it's not possible to safe GKZ, because of an unsaved entity? Did you ever check your database?

Comment: @Z-100 Thank you for your quick responses, I have posted the solution to my task, I was able to solve it. :D

Comment: No problem :) Happy I could assist!

Answer (score 0):

I updated my ServiceImplementation class.

```
    @Override
    public GKZ saveGKZ(GKZ GKZ) {

        //Generate random UUID
        UUID uuid=UUID.randomUUID();  
        GKZ.setuid(uuid);
        
        GKZtrigger gkZtrigger = new GKZtrigger();
        gkZtrigger.setuid(uuid);
        
        gRepository.save(GKZ);
        tRepository.save(gkZtrigger);
        return GKZ;
        
    }
```

Turns out, just creating an instance and then calling the Repository works !

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, you have to save it to GKZTriggerRepository similar to how you save GKZ entity.

```
@Service
public class GKZServiceImpl implements GKZService {
 
    @Autowired
    private GKZInputRepository gRepository;

    @Autowired
    private GKZTriggerRepository gkzTriggerRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional // either everything stored to DB or nothing
    public GKZ saveGKZ(GKZ GKZ) {

        //Generate random UUID
        UUID uuid=UUID.randomUUID();  
        GKZ.setuid(uuid);
    
        gRepository.save(GKZ);

        GKZtrigger gkzTrigger = new GKZtrigger();
        gkzTrigger.setuid(uuid);

        gkzTriggerRepository.save(gkzTrigger);
    
        return GKZ;
    }
}
```

**OR** reference the GKZtrigger entity from the GKZ entity

```
...

@Table(name= "T_CIB_CIBp_GKZ_I")
public class GKZ {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    ...

    @OneToOne
    private GKZtrigger gkzTrigger;

    ...

    public GKZtrigger getGkzTrigger() {
        return this.gkzTrigger;
    }

    public void setGkzTrigger(GKZtrigger gkzTrigger) {
        this.gkzTrigger = gkzTrigger;
    }

    ...

}
```

then you would set GKZtrigger to GKZ entity and JPA will save both for you

```
...

@Override
public GKZ saveGKZ(GKZ GKZ) {

    //Generate random UUID
    UUID uuid=UUID.randomUUID();  
    GKZ.setuid(uuid);

    GKZtrigger gkzTrigger = new GKZtrigger();
    gkzTrigger.setuid(uuid);

    GKZ.setGkzTrigger(gkzTrigger);

    gRepository.save(GKZ); // JPA will save both entities
    
    return GKZ;
}

...
```

And you also have to add

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "gkzTrigger")
private GKZ gkz
```

field to GKZtrigger class so JPA can figure both sides of the relationaship.

If you go down this path I suggest you google "JPA one to one" an read an article at Baeldung (should be the first result). When you got that down, there are also @OneToMany @ManyToOne and @ManyToMany annotations. When your JPA code works, explore the database and see what tables being created and how they relate.

Comment: Thank You! I have added my solution to this question too :D